# puppet: if one file exists then copy another file over

Tags: file, copy, exec, puppet

I am trying to figure out how to make my puppet module work such I need to test if file exists on the client, if it does, then copy another file over. If the file does not exist then do nothing. I can't seem to get it working. Here is my module:

class web-logs::config {

```
  # PATH TO LOG FILES
  $passenger='/var/tmp/puppet_test/passenger'

  # PATH TO LOGROTATE CONFIGS
  $passenger_logrotate='/var/tmp/puppet_test/logrotate.d/passenger'

  exec { 'test1':
     onlyif  => "test -f $passenger",
     path    => ['/usr/bin','/usr/sbin','/bin','/sbin'],
     refreshonly => true,
  } ~>

  exec { 'test2':
     require => Class['web-logs::passenger']
  }
```

And the Class['web-logs::passenger'] looks like this:

```
class web-logs::passenger {
  file { 'passenger':                                                  
    path    => '/var/tmp/puppet_test/logrotate.d/passenger',         
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0644',
    source  => "puppet://${puppetserver}/modules/web-logs/passenger.conf",
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: A clean solution will involve a custom fact. But I'm really curious how this requirement arises in the first place. It would be far simpler to have Puppet create the file regardless of former state.

Answer (score 1):

The exec is failing since you are missing the command to execute. Right now everything fails because of the failing exec requirement in the file resource. This one should do the trick:

```
exec { 'test1':
   command => "/bin/true",                                             
   onlyif  => "test -f $passenger",                            
   path    => ['/usr/bin','/usr/sbin','/bin','/sbin'],
}

# Check if passenger file exists then push logrotate module for passenger
file { 'passenger':                                                  
    path    => '/var/tmp/puppet_test/logrotate.d/passenger',         
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0644',
    source  => "puppet://${puppetserver}/modules/web-logs/passenger.conf",
    require => Exec["test1"],
}
```

If you get disturbed by the message that the command has been successfully executed on each run you could try to modify the exec like this

```
exec { 'test1':
  command => "/bin/false",                                             
  unless  => "test -f $passenger",                            
  path    => ['/usr/bin','/usr/sbin','/bin','/sbin'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `exec test2`. It isn't necessary. You need to `require` the `exec test1` in the `file passenger`. Something like this :

```
class web-logs::passenger {
  file { 'passenger':                                                  
    path    => '/var/tmp/puppet_test/logrotate.d/passenger',         
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0644',
    source  => "puppet://${puppetserver}/modules/web-logs/passenger.conf",
    require => Exec["test1"],
 }
}
```

Comment: But then each single agent run will report the `exec` as failing and the `file` as skipped. This is not quite a solution, more a noisy workaround.

Comment: I wonder if this is not the best way of going about checking to see if file exists. Maybe I need to use facters as environment variables instead of using exec?