# Puppet : file resource only if file exists

Tags: puppet

What I want to do is quite simple :

1.

Copy `/source/file` to `/target/file`. I achieve this using the following:

```
file { 'my_file_copy':
  ensure   => file,
  source   => 'file:/source/file',
  path     => "/target/file",
}
```

2.

However, if file `/source/file` does not exist, I do NOT want it to perform this task.

I am really struggling with this logic. I attempted the solution below but it throws exceptions during puppet run.

[puppet: if one file exists then copy another file over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463506/puppet-if-one-file-exists-then-copy-another-file-over)

Is there a better way of achieving this task ?
Ideally, I would like to only use "file" and avoid using "exec". But at this point I would settle for a solution !

Comment: Well, puppetserver will expect the file to exist in order to compile properly. What do you expect ? I can only think of an IF statement + some feature flag you could be setting in order to exclude the resource. I doubt there is a puppet function to check it source file exists on puppetserver.

Comment: Problem with "if" is that it expects the file on the puppet server not on the client. I want to check if the file exists in the client. One way is to use custom fact but that gets a bit too complicated as it requires ruby knowledge and custom facts execute on each and every server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Puppet is a declarative language where only the end-state is declared, imperative logic such as what you've described - if A, do X - is often hard to express.

Personally, I would try to simply avoid this requirement of having file B copied if and only if file A exists. Often there's a better way.

If the requirement needs to stay, however, then use of Exec here sounds like a pretty good option to me.

```
exec { 'my_file_copy':
  command => 'cp /source/file /target/file',
  onlyif  => 'test -e /source/file',
  creates => '/target/file',
  path    => '/bin',
}
```

Comment: Yes, OK. That is probably more idiomatic. Updated.

Comment: "If A then X" is expressed very often in puppet with the dependency semantics. But in this case, Puppet has not created a built-in-mechanism for the file resource.

Comment: I kinda need the same, the only change is what if the source is some URL, `https://www.file.com/somefile.zip`, now if this zip is available do the processing otherwise exit the code with some message.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this logic:

```
$file = "/source/file"

  exec { "chk_${file}_exist":
    command => "true",
    path    =>  ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin", "/bin"],
    onlyif  => "test -f ${file}"
  }

  file {"/target/file":
    ensure => file,
    source => 'file:/source/file',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0750',
    require => Exec["chk_${file}_exist"],
  }
```

Comment: This would only work if you put the `test` command in the `exec` command. Even then, if you did that, when the conditional fails, it would add an extra failure to your catalog that you would have to remember to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case work only with `if`

```
if (find_file("/source/file"))  {
  file { "/source/file":
    ensure => present,
    mode   => '0644',
    owner  => root,
    group  => root,
  }
}
```