# Puppet execute command only if file does not exist

Tags: puppet

I am trying to use the following code which should perform some action only if a certain file does not exist. If the file exists, it should skip that task. I cannot get it to work.

```
exec {"is_file_there":
  command => "true",
  path    => ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin","/bin"],
  unless  => "test -e /tmp/some_file",
}

somecommand {
  ..
  ..
  require => Exec['is_file_there'],
}
```

As an example, I tried using file but even that did not work. This is just an example for purpose of demonstrating the issue.

```
exec {"is_file_there":
  command => "true",
  path    => ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin","/bin"],
  unless  => "test -e /tmp/some_file",
}

file {'/tmp/success'
  ensure => present,
  require => Exec['is_file_there'],
}
```

EDIT : I am trying to create a dependency between another resource and exec. The other resource does not allow onlyif. The example about file is just that an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Puppet : file resource only if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251255/puppet-file-resource-only-if-file-exists)

Comment: Not really @Matt. In this case, I am trying to create a dependency between another resource ( which does not allow onlyif ) and exec. The example about file is just that an example.

Comment: Puppet doesn't work that way - The earlier exec will have it's `onlyif` condition evaluated, not execute a command, and the file resource will happen after the exec, regardless of it executing the command.    If you wish to conditionally apply puppet code based on the presence of a file, that has to exist or not pre-factor run, and have a custom fact to send the information about the file's existence to your puppet master.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-creates the "creates" option in "exec" will only run "command" if the file doesn't exist:

```
exec {"is_file_there":
  command => "some_action_command",
  path    => ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin","/bin"],
  creates => "/tmp/some_file",
}
```

Comment: Upvoted as a good answer to the question posed in the title.  However, I note that the question appears to present an XY problem, as described in the comments on it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
exec {"Some title":
  command => "Your command",
  path    => ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin","/bin"],
  unless  => "test -e /tmp/some_file",
}
```

So, your command is going to execute **unless** the result of `test -e /tmp/some_file` is success (exit code 0), that is, the file exists.